# Where is php fsockopen function defined?

Tags: php, fsockopen

I want to know where the fsockopen function is defined. Tried to search on google but it gives details about how to use it.

It would be great if anybody can help me in getting the path of the function definition.

I want it for PHP 5.3 on centos.

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about PHP, the definition can be found at http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-7.1/ext/standard/fsock.c#127.